# Unit comparison between two molecular dynamics simulations with different time step

Tags: molecular-dynamics

I need some clarification regarding the time step used in the molecular dynamics simulations. In the first simulation the time step was 1 nanosecond and in the second simulation the time step in 10 ns. Now I want to compare the results of these two simulations. For example take mean-square displacement.
$$
MSD(1ns) = \frac{nm^{2}}{ns} = 10^{-9} m^{2}/s \\
MSD(10ns) = \frac{nm^{2}}{10 ns} = 10^{-8 } m^{2}/s
$$
What I did above is correct or I should not include `10ns` in the denominator of the second `MSD`?

Comment: The values you measure and expressions with them over a fixed time interval should be (largely) independent of the internals of the integration method. So the denominator should be the length of the actual time interval. In your case you should be comparing 10 steps of 1 ns with one step of 10 ns.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Just for more clarity: If the time step is `10ns` in the simulation, then I need to divide the `MSD` with `10ns` right?

Comment: I think you are mixing two separate things, the computation of the result you want and the combination of the units to get a conversion factor. In the units the data numbers should not occur, when evaluating the data you need to make sure that they have the same or compatible units, and when comparing two different computations you need to make sure that you are comparing overall the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I've a clear head!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.